Custom settings per SwaggerDoc
I am configuring multiple Swagger documents for different customers.
Is there a way to configure Swagger to have different settings per Swagger document.
For example:
I create 2 documents:

c.SwaggerDoc('A', new OpenApiInfo...
c.SwaggerDoc('B', new OpenApiInfo...

I would like different configuration based on the document

SwaggerDoc A would have options.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName);
SwaggerDoc B would have options.CustomSchemaIds(x => SomeCustomIdMethod(x));

